# Servlet context injection fail while using jersey test framework

Tags: java, testing, jersey, freemarker, servlets

I'm beginning with jersey and trying to get freemarker working with it using TDD. I want to make a `ViewProcessor` for my templates, but fail to inject the servlet context in the class.

Here is the class code :

```
@Provider
public class myProcessor implements ViewProcessor<Template> {

    [...]
   
    @Context
    public ServletContext myContext;

    [...]

 freemarkerConfiguration.setTemplateLoader(
       new WebappTemplateLoader(myContext,
           myContext.getInitParameter("freemarker.template.path")));

    [...]
    }
```

And here is the test code :

```
public class myProcessorTest extends JerseyTest {
   
    public static myProcessor mp;
   
    public myProcessorTest() throws Exception{
        super(new WebAppDescriptor.Builder("com.domain").build());
    }
   
    @Test
    public void firstTest(){
        mp = new myProcessor();
        String path = new String("test.ftl");
        Template template = mp.resolve(path);
        assertNotNull(template);
    }
}
```

I use maven with dependencies as follow:

```maven
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.jersey.jersey-test-framework</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-test-framework-grizzly</artifactId>
    <version>1.5-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

My code runs fine when I deploy to my local jetty server. But if I want to test the code in my IDE, it failed to inject the servlet context (`@Context`) : `myContext` is `null` when I run the test :/

I think I'm missing something, but I'm a complete beginner with servlet world.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a technique for testing a specific resource class, using Jersey Test Framework, with servlet support.  Also demonstrates how to customize the `ServletContext`.

```
import javax.servlet.ServletContext;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Context;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Feature;
import javax.ws.rs.core.FeatureContext;
import org.glassfish.jersey.server.ResourceConfig;
import org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer;
import org.glassfish.jersey.test.DeploymentContext;
import org.glassfish.jersey.test.JerseyTest;
import org.glassfish.jersey.test.ServletDeploymentContext;
import org.glassfish.jersey.test.TestProperties;
import org.glassfish.jersey.test.grizzly.GrizzlyWebTestContainerFactory;
import org.glassfish.jersey.test.spi.TestContainerException;
import org.glassfish.jersey.test.spi.TestContainerFactory;

import static org.mockito.Mockito.mock;

/**
 * A base class for testing web resources.
 */
public abstract class WebResourceTest extends JerseyTest {

    /**
     * Creates a JAX-RS resource configuration for test purposes.
     */
    @Override
    protected abstract ResourceConfig configure();

    /**
     * Creates a test container factory with servlet support.
     */
    @Override
    protected TestContainerFactory getTestContainerFactory() throws TestContainerException {
        return new GrizzlyWebTestContainerFactory();
    }

    /**
     * Configures a deployment context for JAX-RS.
     */
    @Override
    protected DeploymentContext configureDeployment() {
        ResourceConfig app = configure();
        app.register(new Feature() {
            @Context
            ServletContext servletContext;

            @Override
            public boolean configure(FeatureContext context) {
                servletContext.setAttribute("example", new Object());
                return true;
            }
        });
        return ServletDeploymentContext.forServlet(new ServletContainer(app)).build();
    }
}
```

A usage example:

```
import org.glassfish.jersey.server.ResourceConfig;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Context;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.spy;
import static org.testng.Assert.assertEquals;
import static org.junit.Assert.*;

public class MyResourceTest extends WebResourceTest {

    private MyResource resource;

    @Override
    protected ResourceConfig configure() {
        resource = spy(new MyResource());
        return new ResourceConfig().register(resource);
    }

    @Test
    public void testSomething() {
        Response r = target("/myresource").request().get();
        assertEquals(200, r.getStatus());
        assertEquals(1, resource.count);
    }
}

@Path("/myresource")
public class MyResource {
    int count = 0;

    @Context
    protected ServletContext servletContext;

    @GET
    public void get() {
       Object attr = servletContext.getAttribute("example");
       count++;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a couple of ways to do it. Remove the constructor and implement a configure() method like this:

```
public class myProcessorTest extends JerseyTest {

    public static myProcessor mp;

    @Override
    protected AppDescriptor configure() {
    return new WebAppDescriptor.Builder("com.domain")
        .contextParam("contextConfigLocation", "classpath:/applicationContext.xml")
        .contextPath("/").servletClass(SpringServlet.class)
        .contextListenerClass(ContextLoaderListener.class)
        .requestListenerClass(RequestContextListener.class)
        .build();
  }
```

or alternatively you can annotate your test with the spring context:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration("classpath:applicationContext.xml")
public class MyProcessorTest extends JerseyTest {

  public static myProcessor mp;
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a solution to this problem that does not require spring, assuming you are using the default/standard Grizzy2 test framework provider. According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17989236/2528639) the `jersey-test-framework-provider-grizzly2` framework provider does not utilize a servlet environment in constructing the application context. Your symptoms result from there being no `ServletContext` instance to inject.

The workaround is to provide the test container for the unit tests yourself. First, modify your dependencies:

```
<!--<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.test-framework.providers</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-test-framework-provider-grizzly2</artifactId>
    <version>2.25</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>-->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.test-framework</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-test-framework-core</artifactId>
    <version>2.25</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-container-grizzly2-servlet</artifactId>
    <version>2.25</version>
</dependency>
```

Then, modify your test to provide a Grizzy servlet container:

```
@Override
protected TestContainerFactory getTestContainerFactory() throws TestContainerException {
  return (final URI baseUri, final DeploymentContext deploymentContext) -> 
    new TestContainer() {
    private HttpServer server = null;

    @Override
    public ClientConfig getClientConfig() {
      return null;
    }

    @Override
    public URI getBaseUri() {
      return baseUri;
    }

    @Override
    public void start() {
      try {
        this.server = GrizzlyWebContainerFactory.create(baseUri, Collections
            .singletonMap("jersey.config.server.provider.packages", "<your-package-name>"));
      } catch (final ProcessingException | IOException cause) {
        throw new TestContainerException(cause);
      }
    }

    @Override
    public void stop() {
      this.server.shutdownNow();
    }
  };
}
```

I assume that you are going to use this in multiple unit tests, so it may be wise to extend `JerseyTest` so this common configuration may be performed automatically. Additionally, it may be worth reviewing [`org.glassfish.jersey.test.grizzly.GrizzlyTestContainerFactory`](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.glassfish.jersey.test-framework.providers/jersey-test-framework-provider-grizzly2/2.19/org/glassfish/jersey/test/grizzly/GrizzlyTestContainerFactory.java/) to see if there is any functionality provided by the test container that you wish to emulate/preserve. The example provided should be able to be dropped into your test to at least confirm this is a fix.

**EDIT:** In my own implementation, I required the ability to still supply a `ResourceConfig` when generating the server. I suspect that this is likely to be the common case for other Jersey Test Framework users. A working example of the proposed `TestContainerFactory` follows.

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URI;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

import javax.servlet.ServletContext;
import javax.ws.rs.ProcessingException;
import javax.ws.rs.core.UriBuilder;

import org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServer;
import org.glassfish.grizzly.servlet.WebappContext;
import org.glassfish.hk2.utilities.binding.AbstractBinder;
import org.glassfish.jersey.client.ClientConfig;
import org.glassfish.jersey.grizzly2.httpserver.GrizzlyHttpServerFactory;
import org.glassfish.jersey.test.DeploymentContext;
import org.glassfish.jersey.test.spi.TestContainer;
import org.glassfish.jersey.test.spi.TestContainerException;
import org.glassfish.jersey.test.spi.TestContainerFactory;
import org.glassfish.jersey.test.spi.TestHelper;


public class RestTestContainerFactory implements TestContainerFactory {      
  public static class RestTestContainer implements TestContainer {
    private static final Logger LOGGER = Logger.getLogger(RestTestContainer.class.getName());

    private URI baseUri = null;
    private final HttpServer server;

    public RestTestContainer(final URI baseUri, final DeploymentContext context) {
      this.baseUri = UriBuilder.fromUri(baseUri).path(context.getContextPath()).build();
      if(LOGGER.isLoggable(Level.INFO)) {
        LOGGER.info("Creating RestRestContainer configured at the base URI "+TestHelper.zeroPortToAvailablePort(baseUri));
      }

      try {
        final WebappContext webContext = new WebappContext("TestContext", context.getContextPath());
        context.getResourceConfig()
               .register(new AbstractBinder() {
                @Override
                protected void configure() {
                  bind(webContext).to(ServletContext.class);
                }
              });
        this.server = GrizzlyHttpServerFactory.createHttpServer(this.baseUri, context.getResourceConfig(), false);
        webContext.deploy(this.server);

      } catch (final ProcessingException cause) {
        throw new TestContainerException(cause);
      }
    }

    @Override
    public ClientConfig getClientConfig() {
      return null;
    }

    @Override
    public URI getBaseUri() {
      return baseUri;
    }

    @Override
    public void start() {
      if(server.isStarted()) {
        LOGGER.warning("Ignoring start request - RestTestContainer is already started");
      } else {
        LOGGER.fine("Starting RestTestContainer...");
        try {
          server.start();
          if(baseUri.getPort() == 0) {
            baseUri = UriBuilder.fromUri(baseUri)
                .port(server.getListener("grizzly").getPort())
                .build();
            LOGGER.info("Started GrizzlyTestContainer at the base URI "+baseUri);
          }
        }
        catch(final ProcessingException | IOException cause) {
          throw new TestContainerException(cause);
        }
      }
    }

    @Override
    public void stop() {
      if(server.isStarted()) {
        LOGGER.fine("Stopping RestTestContainer...");
        server.shutdownNow();
      } else {
        LOGGER.warning("Ignoring stop request - RestTestContainer is already stopped");
      }
    }
  }

  @Override
  public TestContainer create(final URI baseUri, final DeploymentContext context) {
    return new RestTestContainer(baseUri,context);
  }
}
```

Frustratingly, grizzly's `GrizzlyWebContainerFactory` will provide a servlet context, but not configure with a resource config. Inversely, `GrizzlyHttpServerFactory` will configure an application with a `ResourceConfig`, but will not provide a web context.

We can work around this by creating the `WebappContext` (extends `ServletContext`) manually, configuring it, and then injecting it into the resource config by means of an `AbstractBinder`.