# jersey2 Unit testing,HttpServletRequest is null

Tags: java, rest, jersey

Ask everybody to help?

jersey Bug connection: [1]: https://java.net/jira/browse/JERSEY-2412

The servlet request, response and context not injected into the class when I using test provider (tested jetty and grizzly2).
I using packages annotation to pull up the application.

Do you have any other way?

---

```
 public class VMResourceTest extends BaseTest {  

    @Test  
    public void testCreateVm() {  

    String bodyData = loadClassPathData(CLASS_PATH+File.separator+"tools"+File.separator+"createVm.json");  
        Response response = target("/tool/cloud/vrm/fm/ghca_vms").queryParam("platform_id", "A22A4B0C3AEC49F5916EA8CC01F56E9A")  
                    .request().header("X-Auth-GHCA-User-ID", "X-Auth-GHCA-User-ID")  
                    .post(Entity.entity(bodyData, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON));  
        assertEquals("200", response.getStatus());  
    }  
}
```

---

```
    public class BaseTest extends JerseyTest{  
       public String CLASS_PATH = "classpath:";  
       public WebTarget target;  
       public Client client;  

      @Override  
      protected Application configure() {  
        enable(TestProperties.LOG_TRAFFIC);  
        enable(TestProperties.DUMP_ENTITY);  
        ResourceConfig rc = new    ResourceConfig().packages("com.ghca.easyview.server.api.resource");  
        rc.register(SpringLifecycleListener.class);  
        rc.register(RequestContextListener.class);  

        rc.property("contextConfigLocation", "classpath:spring/spring-config.xml");  
        return rc;  
    }  



        public String loadClassPathData(String classFilePath){  
           File schemaContextFile = null;  
           String result = "";  
        try {  
            schemaContextFile = readSchemaFile(classFilePath);  
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new  FileReader(schemaContextFile));
            String s = null;  
            while((s = br.readLine())!=null){ 
                result = result + "\n" +s;  
            }  
            br.close();      
        } catch (IOException e) {  
            e.printStackTrace();  
        }  
        return result;  
    }  
    }
```

---

```
    @Component  
    @Path("tool/cloud/vrm")  
    public class VMResource extends BaseResource{  

    @Autowired  
    private VMService vmService;  

    @Context  
    public HttpServletRequest request;  
    @Context  
    public HttpServletResponse response;  


    @POST  
    @Path("{platform_type}/ghca_vms")  
    @Consumes({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON,MediaType.APPLICATION_XML})  
    @Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON,MediaType.APPLICATION_XML})  
    public Response createVm(@PathParam("platform_type") String platformType,  
            @QueryParam("platform_id") String platformId) {}
```

request and response is null.

Answer (score 8):

You need to configure the `JerseyTest` for a Servlet environment. In your `JerseyTest`, you should have something like

```
@Override
protected TestContainerFactory getTestContainerFactory() {
    return new GrizzlyWebTestContainerFactory();
}

@Override
protected DeploymentContext configureDeployment() {
    ResourceConfig config = new ResourceConfig(SessionResource.class);
    return ServletDeploymentContext.forServlet(
                             new ServletContainer(config)).build();
}
```

If you look at the `ServletDeploymentContext.forServlet`, it returns a [`ServletDeploymentContext.Builder`](https://jersey.java.net/apidocs/latest/jersey/org/glassfish/jersey/test/ServletDeploymentContext.Builder.html). If you look at the Javadoc, you will see some familiar looking methods, like `initParam(...,...)`, `addListener`, etc. This is just like building your web.xml programmatically. Just keep chaining methods, then build.

With the above configuration, you no longer need to override the `configure` method in the `JerseyTest`. Just add the `ResourceConfig` like seen above.

See other test examples [here](https://github.com/jersey/jersey/tree/master/test-framework/providers/grizzly2/src/test/java/org/glassfish/jersey/test/grizzly/web)

Also See related:

- [How to in-memory unit test Spring-Jersey](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28614846/2587435)